# Delete verb not working in IIS 8 windows 2012 R2

Tags: windows, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, http-verbs, delete-method

Larvel website hosted on Windows server 2012 R2 but I am not able to delete Attachments in the website.

```
Please refer screenshot now
Error message 
Request URL:http://13.232.72.80/api/delete-form-data/form-field/33
Request method:DELETE
Remote address:13.232.72.80:80
Status code:
405
Version:HTTP/1.1
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYPYc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to call asp.net web api with delete method?

If this is your requirement, I suggest you could try below solution to solve this issue.

1.Open your IIS manager and locate the web sites and find the hanlder mapping.  Find ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0, double click it. Click Request Restrictions... button and on Verbs tab, add both DELETE.

[image]

2.Remove the WebDAVModule for your web application.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```